# Can not set natIP to an IP resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created a static external IP with Deployment Manager code. No Problem.

I'd like to use this IP to create an Compute Engine Instance.

Setting the field "networkIP" to the URL of a IP ressource works fine, but setting the field "natIP" to such a resource does not work. "natIP" only works with IP addresses (e.g. 35.241.113.34) and not with links to an IP a resource.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a design inconsistency in the API?

Example code:

```
    'name': 'status-tool',
    'type': 'compute.v1.instance',
    'properties': {
    ...
            'networkInterfaces': [{
                    'networkIP': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ccp-management/regions/europe-west1/addresses/...',        # works
                    'accessConfigs': [{
                            'name': 'External NAT',
                            'type': 'ONE_TO_ONE_NAT',
                            'natIP': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ccp-management/regions/europe-west1/addresses/...',    # does not work
                    }]
            }]        
    ...
```

Setting "natIP" to such a value results in a ResourceErrorMessage (Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for raising this issue. Setting the field “NAT IP” seems to be a known issue already been forwarded to our engineering team. However, there is no fixed ETA, about the resolution of this issue. I would suggest that you follow the PIT thread below regarding further update on this issue.

https://issuetracker.google.com/118634820